# Java program is parking before it's executed every line in actionPerformed

Tags: java, swing

In a Swing program I'm writing, there is a button with an action listener. In the actionPerformed function for that ActionListener, there are a couple function calls.

My issue is that the final function call in actionPerformed is getting skipped, but it does get executed if the button gets clicked again.

I'm verifying this by stepping through the program with a debugger. I'll step into the first function, but after the first function returns, the debugger stops, saying "The application is running." If I pause it, it's in a function called park() in Unsafe.class. If I'm not mistaken, park should be called while the program is waiting for input, right?

Here is the relevant code:

```java
removeDayB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //action listener for button being clicked
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        // JFrame a = new RemoveDayDialog(listOfDays); TODO: I don't think this line does anything
        String itemToRemove = comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if (comboBox.getSelectedItem() == noDaysString) {
            // TODO: Need to handle this case
        } else {
            listOfDays.removeDay(itemToRemove);
            // TODO: This next next line is not getting executed
            refreshComboBox();
        }
    }
});
```

`listOfDays.removeDay(itemToRemove);` is being executed, I can step into it, and the desired effects are taking place. The problem is that `refreshComboBox();` is not getting called. It's just a helper function to keep the items in a combo box updated with the items in a container within another class.

What could be causing that line to be skipped?

EDIT: A comment pointed out an extremely simple mistake that I was making. the listOfDays.removeDay(itemToRemove) call was indeed throwing an exception. I'm becomming familiar with a new IDE, and apparently while debugging, I don't see the exception get thrown. Once I ran the program outside of the debugger, the exception was thrown and the mistake that I was making became clear.

```
public void removeDay(CharSequence str) {
    for (Day day : days) {
        if (day.getDateAsString().equals(str)) {
            days.remove(day);
        }
    }
}
```

The exception was related to concurrency, I guess removing an item from days (ArrayList) while still iterating through it is a no-no. Fixed it by adding a break after `days.remove(day)`

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Don't use `==` to compare `String` instances, use `equals()`. 3) `This next next line is not getting executed` How do you know that? Have you done code tracing? Put a `println` in the method?

Comment: *"`listOfDays.removeDay(itemToRemove);` is being executed, I can step into it"* Too late to edit my comment, but ignore the third point.

Comment: Is, `listOfDays.removeDay` throwing an exception? What is happening in listOfDays.removeDay,  there are a number of reasons it could be blocking.

Comment: @matt that's exactly what was happening, didn't see the stack trace from the debugger. If you'll write this as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your debugger, if `listOfDays.removeDay` is throwing an exception, it will appears as though your actionListener is completing its method, but it is actually ending early.

This might also be tough to spot because, the EDT will print the stacktrace and continue handling subsequent events.